# ESENT table browser?

Tags: database, nosql, esent

Has anyone had any experience with the Esent database engine? I've been taking a look at what it's used for, and am getting excited.

> Active Directory is implemented on top of an Indexed Sequential Access Method (ISAM) table manager, historically called "Jet." This same table manager is used by Exchange, File Replication service (FRS) the security configuration editor, Certificate Services, Windows Internet Name Service (WINS), and various other Windows components.
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961824.aspx

There's also a c# wrapper around the API http://www.codeplex.com/ManagedEsent, and is being used by Ayende Rahien's DivanDB (.net document storage LINQ engine)  https://rhino-tools.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/rhino-tools/branches/rhino-divandb

Anyhow- does anyone know of a "table browser" / some for of GUI for managing Esent?

Answer (score 4):

I've seen one here:

http://www.woanware.co.uk/forensics/esedbviewer.html

*Update:* The URL has changed

Comment: Fixed link: http://www.woanware.co.uk/?page_id=89

Comment: Does not work here (some others do). Windows 10 x64.

Answer (score 4):

ESEDatabaseView, fast and works well:
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ese_database_view.html

Answer (score 2):

<strike>ESENT Studio - http://www.orthogonal.com.au/computers/esent/</strike>

Apparently, ESENT Studio is dead. It was replaced by EsentWorkbench - https://dev.azure.com/orthogonal/EsentWorkbench/

Comment: The link is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

I found this : http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/ESE.htm

There is a sample vb.net app that displays the tables + columns for an edb file.   I'm using Win7 x64, and I couldnt open the database given in the sample path 'C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\DataStore.edb' - I received a "The database page size does not match the engine" error.

However, I created a new edb file using the c# managed api, and was able to use the browser with this file.

Hope it helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

[EsentWorkbench](https://bitbucket.org/gfkeogh/esentworkbench/wiki/Home), A WPF desktop application for manipulating ESENT databases.

Comment: New link: https://bitbucket.org/orthoprog/esentworkbench/wiki/Home

Comment: The new new link: https://dev.azure.com/orthogonal/EsentWorkbench/ (also linked in answer above)

Answer (score -1):

Here is yet another example of an ESE Database Viewer (with source code!).  So, if you're looking for an example of how to create a GUI to view ESE data, this might be helpful.

This one can view the table contents, plus the schema and indexes

http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/ViewESE.html

PS: I am the author...